# Joint distribution law for binomial value

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution

If X1,X2,X3,X4 be samples for the population X~B(1,q). What the joint distribution law of samples here?
I just added a photo. Can someone check if it’s correct or not?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXwiK.jpg)

Comment: Assuming they are independent, the joint probability  is equal to the product of the individual probabilities.  Or are you interested in the distribution of their sum (the clue is in the question title) or their mean?  What have you tried?

Comment: Is that p^x1(1−p)^(1-x1),  then I need to multiply x2,x3,x4 like this in order or simply the joint distribution law here is 4p^x(1−p)^(1-x)?  I'm terrible at this,  it's taking me so long to understand these concepts. If you could possibly make it clear, it would be so helpful